# Why does this chord progression work?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-progressions

I have been playing this chord progression that I came up with (which is almost the same shape constantly), but I want to understand why it sounds good.

The progression is: DminAdd9 C Bb6 A7

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalusian_cadence

Answer (score 11):

It probably sounds good for reasons other than music theory: you recognize it from all kinds of songs, including ["Hit the Road Jack."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8Tiz6INF7I) Your progression is the same, you just added a 9th in the first chord and a 6th in the third chord.

This particular progression is an example of what we call the [lament bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lament_bass). Also called a "step-descent bass," it's exactly what it sounds like: a bassline that moves down by step. Your progression is an embellished i–♭VII–♭VI–V, which is a very common lament bass progression. So common, in fact, it has its own name: the [Andalusian cadence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalusian_cadence).

As for your added notes, note that they are chord tones of the next chord: The add9 above D (E) is in the subsequent C chord, and the 6 above B♭ (G) is the 7th of the A7 chord.

See also [What chords should accompany descending bass notes in a scale?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/70104/what-chords-should-accompany-descending-bass-notes-in-a-scale) for some other harmonizations of this idea.

Comment: A variation on the *Spanish sequence*?

Comment: 'Music theory' is fine with this progression, it both recognises and labels it - you've quoted a couple of the labels.  Theory does not demand that a progression should be all in one scale, or describable as a string of dominants and resolutions - two things that seem to legitimise a progression for many people.  "Theory describes, it does not command."

Comment: Pretty much the same as what Knopfler plays in "Sultans of Swing" throughout the song as well.

Comment: @LaurencePayne I agree. Just out of curiosity, did anything in my answer suggest I believed otherwise?

Comment: 'It probably sounds good for reasons other than music theory' suggests that theory can't cope with it.

Comment: @LaurencePayne Oh, I see. That wasn't my intent, and I figured the remaining three paragraphs would make that clear. Thanks!